# Can we develop non linear slider with react component slider?

Tags: reactjs, slider

I want to create a time slider from 0 - 23 hour. But I want to show the part from 0-9 as a smaller portion with exponential values and working hours (9 - 17) as a major portion as shown in the image below. Is it possible with  react component slider ?

[Time slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKzSP.png)

Same result can be produced through [react nouislider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nouislider-react). But it is a not native react library. Should I continue with this?

**Example:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/nouislider-react-example-8rbp8?fontsize=14